# Javascript syntax error token

Tags: javascript

this is my code

```
var text = "";
var text += "function "+ funcName + "(){";
var text += "\n";
```

and this is the error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token += **

How can I solve it?

Comment: Get rid of `var` on the lines after the first; it's completely unnecessary and it's causing your problem.

Comment: Every time you use `var` it's like you're re-declaring the variable.

Comment: Once you've declared a variable with `var` in a particular lexical context, you don't need to do it again.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté so `+=` is valid in a `var` initializer clause?

Comment: @Pointy my bad, I missed that `+=` was being used in a `var` declaration.

Comment: @Pointy since you were the first to comment, you should probably submit an answer (gets a +1 from me).

Comment: I'll just note that @MelanciaUK's comment is not really clear. `var` declarations are parsed and their identifiers are added as properties of the Environment Record object in the entering phase of the execution context. That means a `var` re-declaration is redundant and does not re-initialize a variable. Try: `var a=1; var a; alert(a);` alerts `1`. However, `+=` is not valid a token after the identifier of a variable declaration, hence the syntax error.

Comment: @Pointy feel free to do an editorial review of my comment above and post as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Oh I figure it's obvious now; this is a pretty simple question. I will delete my comments since the whole thing is basically just a misunderstanding of the language syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redeclaring an already declared variable.  Instead, you should have:

```
var text = "";
text += "function "+ funcName + "(){";
text += "\n";
```

You can't `+=` a variable that hasn't been assigned a value yet, since there is not an initial value to be incrementing.

Comment: The correct answer is in *Fabrício Matté's* comment.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare your variables once.

```
var funcName = "myFunction";
var text = "";
text += "function " + funcName + "(){";
text += "\n";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/66d0t7k0/3/

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` operator appends text to an existing variable -- it is a syntax error to use it in a new variable declaration.  So you need either (which is syntactically correct but nonsense):

```
var text = "";
var text = "function "+ funcName + "(){";
var text = "\n";
```

Or:

```
var text = "";
text += "function "+ funcName + "(){";
text += "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the var from the second line and third line, you are declaring a new variable from every line.

```
var text = "";
    text += "function "+ funcName + "(){";
    text += "\n";
```